# List file names in order of file size in BASH

Tags: bash

So, I'm trying to perform batch processing on a lot of files, but I want the batch processing to start off with the smallest files first. What I need to do is get all the file names in ascending order, sorted by the file size. I've seen some examples, but one problem is that some of the file names contain spaces, hyphens, underscores, and other special characters, so I can't find anything that works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ls -rS` will do the trick. The man page explains more: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html

Comment: This will not handle files with space between them as the question suggests.

Comment: @Inian why not? `ls` will handle files with spaces, carriage-returns just perfectly; the *only* problem I see is, that the OP intends to use the output of this as input to their script - but your answer doesn't provide a solution for that either.

Answer (score 1):

**`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -c | sort -n`**

The above example lists files under the current directory in ascending order of size. The `-print0` argument to the find command instructs it to use the `null '\0'` character instead of whitespace as the delimiter between search results. On the other side of the pipe, the `-0` arguments prepares the `xargs` command to do the same thing. This will handle whitespace characters in file name as ordinary characters.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec wc -c {} + | sort -n` is a more efficient alternative that is also POSIX-compliant (`-print0` is not). The problem, however, is that `wc`, with more than 1 filename argument, prints a summary line in the form of `<bytes> total`, which you'd need to filter out. Note that with a large number of input files `wc` may be invoked more than once (if not all filenames fit on a single command line), which makes filtering the summary lines trickier, especially since there could be _files_ named `total`.

Answer (score 1):

If:

- you're not worried about filenames with embedded *newlines*, and
- you don't need the actual file sizes, just the filenames sorted by underlying file size,

then [K. Matthews' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316633/45375) should work for you.

Otherwise, assuming you have *GNU* utilities:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\t%f\0' | 
  sort -zn -k1,1 |
    while read -r -d '' size name; do echo "[$size] [$name]"; done
```

<sup>`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` limits matches to files directly located in `.`, similar to `ls` (though hidden files are always included). Omit it process files in the entire *subtree*.</sup>

The `while` loop shows one way to further process the NUL-terminated output produced by `find`'s `-printf '...\0'` and `sort -z`.
Using `awk -F'\t' -v RS='\0' ...` is another.

Note that `find`'s `-printf` and  `sort`'s `-z` are nonstandard, GNU-specific extensions, as is using `'\0'` as the `RS` value with `awk`.